# Symfony-Doctrine best way to import data from different databases

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 3.4, i need to daily-import some data from a table to another.
Source table is stored in a DB in SQL Server.
Destination table is stored in a MySql DB.

Which is the best way to implement this?
I was thinking about a command with a cron that perform the import, but i don't know if i should use Doctrine Entities, or SQL and storing data in an array and then copy it in destination table... some suggestion? Thanks

Comment: How many rows have you got to migrate per day ? If possible it is better to keep the doctrine entities for object consistency. But if you have many rows to migrate per day you could go for a native SQL query to increase performance and avoid the doctrine entities hydration process  :)

Comment: In addition to @Mcsky http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html (you could post it as answer)

Comment: Nice tips @goto batch processing is mandatory while using doctrine with a big set of data

Comment: @Mcsky it's about 6k rows. I think goto suggestion is my solution, i'll try and let you know! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is better to use the doctrine entities, because they have your **business rules** (custom methods with some logics for example)

Moreover you could partially load the entities with `EntityManager->createNativeQuery(...)` with selecting only the properties/relation you need, so the doctrine hydratation process will take less memory.

As @goto mentionned in comment, the [batch process](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) is the key while manipulating big set of doctrine entities (it take so much memory without that)

There is no one good solution it depend how many rows you have to migrate per day. If you have to handle very huge set of data you could consider use native SQL query to simply populate array for performance.

I hope it's helped :)